# Difference between "end" and "end)"?

Tags: lua

A while ago I had stumbled upon script tutorials where `end` was used. But then, a few pages later, I've found an `end)` instead of just `end`. So I was troubled by this, what is the closing bracket meant to do?

Comment: [No taglines please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Too localized? / To close an open parentheses somewhere, of course.

Comment: So it's supposed to be something to end a local function?

Comment: May we see the snippet of code itself? That may help to give things some context.

Comment: like this? `table.sort( t, function(a,b) return a>b end ) `

Comment: Not related to `end;` or `end.`.

Comment: A "smiley end" lexem is valid in Lua syntax :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `end)` syntax. There is `end` and `)`, both with their own meanings. `end` closes a block (initiated with `if`, `for`, `do`, `while` or `function`) and `)` closes something that started with `(`, an expression in parentheses, parameter list etc. You have to use `end` where a block was started, and use `)` where something was started with `(`.

Since the only way a block can appear in an expression is via a function, both those parts of syntax can appear together, if a function is a part of a complex expression or an argument list. However, it's nothing special really, something like `end}` or `end]` can appear the same way.

```
local func = function() print("hello") end
string.dump(func)
```

This is the same as:

```
string.dump(function() print("hello") end)
```

`end` is a part of the `function` syntax (function expression), and `)` is a part of the `(` syntax (function call here).

The first line in the first piece of code can be also written like this:

```
local func = (function() print("hello") end)
```

Here, `)` just closes the first parenthesis, and the expression is identical to the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about ROBLOX's modded version of Lua, if so then
end) would end :connect, for example.

```
workspace.part.Touched:connect(function(part)
--stuff
end)
```

If not then refer to llidanS4's answer.

Comment: How is that a modded version of Lua?

Comment: The functions and loops are not functionnal in actual lua because they belong to the RBXLua language, that's why it is modded.